# How to write one read, insert, update, delete method that does the job for each database models?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, generics, interface

I always had to write four methods (read, insert, update, delete) **for each model** in MVC.
I need to know if there's a better way to write less code and use some C# features like interfaces, generic types , I don't know ... etc.
And let's say I have these tables which map to their corresponding models generated by ADO.Net Entity Data Model.

[image]

Comment: you can probably write a generic method for each command (select, insert etc`) but don't expect it to be better. It's better to use a different command for each table.

Comment: Do you use same method for eating banana, watermelon and pineapple?

Comment: Why are you writing these methods at all? EF has CRUD features built-in.

Comment: [Someone had the same question not so long ago.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684337/i-want-to-write-one-common-stored-procedure-to-insert-data-in-any-table-of-my-da) read my answer to that question for more details.

Comment: Take a look at the CQRS pattern. https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/05/05/cqrs-with-mediatr-and-automapper/

Answer (score 1):

For simple CRUD logic, you can use generic repository pattern. Here is example:

```
interface IRepository<T> where T: class
{
    List<T> GetAll();
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Remove(T entity);
}
```

Implementation with Entity Framework (replace DbContext with your context class):

```
class GenericRepository<T>: IRepository<T> where T: class
{
    public virtual List<T> GetAll()
    {
        using(var context = new DbContext())
        {
            return content.Set<T>().ToList();
        }
    }

    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        using(var context = new DbContext())
        {
            context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        using(var context = new DbContext())
        {
            context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public virtual void Remove(T entity)
    {
        using(var context = new DbContext())
        {
            context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

All methods are virtual so you can override them if necessary. You can use this repository directly (discouraged), or subclass it for specific type:

```
class UserRepository: GenericRepository<User>
{
   // other query methods here
}
```