# Dynamic T-SQL stored procedure to insert in differents tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic

What is the best way to achieve this

```
INSERT INTO @TableName (@ColumnNames)
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLResult;
```

Where `@TableName`, `@ColumnNames`, `@SQLResult` are `varchar` variables

I am trying to avoid do a separate insert for each table.

Comment: don't.  use a case statement or investigate why your api is designed this way.

Comment: @Hogan I'm trying avoid a case because are 23 differents tables should I need populate for now. The TableName is a parameter of the SP which I use to insert into the tables

Comment: In this case, you **must** resort to using dynamic SQL - you **cannot** parametrize table and column names in straight T-SQL.

Comment: Sounds like bad design.  I'd honestly try looking into redesigning whatever process this is, if it's a viable option.

Comment: Just write the 23 stored procedures.  If that is to hard you can make the procedures with dynamic HTML that will be more secure, run faster AND is a better design.

Comment: @SantiagoSalaberry You don't want to avoid writing 23 insert procs, given the downsides. Please also see this nearly identical question on DBA.StackExchange: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105541/stored-procedure-which-insert-update-delete-any-tablefor-any-table-where-tab

Comment: I agree with all the above comments, however, treating your question as academic, you would use a cursor that populates the TableName and ColumnNames variables and then runs the EXEC.  The cursor would presumably be populated by selecting from some sort of metadata table.

Comment: @Hogan - I'm aware of the [`CASE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) _expression_ in TSQL, but what is the `CASE` _statement_? There isn't one listed under [control-of-flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174290.aspx).

Comment: @HABO they are the same thing. In fact even MS can't be consistent. You need look no further than the page you linked. Down in the remarks section.."The CASE statement evaluates its conditions sequentially..." While it is correct that it is an expression in t-sql the common terminology has been statement in every other language. It has been this way in t-sql since, well forever.

Comment: @HABO - sure there is no exact CASE statement in flow of control but a buncha IF ... ELSE will give you the same functionality.  My note was a shorthand for that kind of construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I appreciate all your comments. And I agree that SQL dynamic is a pain to debug (Thanks God, management studio has this possibility). And, of course there are hundreds of different solutions

I solved it in this way finally, more or less I try to explain why this solution of SQL dynamic. The client uses xlsx spreadsheets to enter certain data, so I read the spreadsheets and I insert the (data depends on the spreadsheet to insert into the proper table). Later the data in the tables are exported to XML to send a third party sofware.

```
SET @SEL = N'';
DECLARE sel_cursor CURSOR
FOR (SELECT  sc.name as field
      FROM sys.objects so INNER JOIN sys.columns sc ON so.[object_id]=sc.[object_id]
      WHERE so.name= @TableName and sc.name not in ('InitDate', 'EndDate', 'Version', 'Status'));

SET @SEL = ''; set @i = 0;
OPEN sel_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM sel_cursor INTO @field
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    set @sel = @sel + ', '+ @field 
    set @i   = 1;
    FETCH NEXT FROM sel_cursor INTO @field
END
CLOSE sel_cursor;
DEALLOCATE sel_cursor;


SET @SQL = N''
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SELECT * INTO XLImport FROM OPENROWSET'
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'('
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'''+','
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'''Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES;'
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'Database='+@file +''''+ ','
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'''select * from ['+ @SheetName + '$]'''+');'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

SET @SQL = N'';
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'
SELECT '+''''+CAST(@initDate AS VARCHAR(10))+'''' +', '+ ''''+CAST(@endDate AS VARCHAR(10))+'''' 
      + ', '+ CAST(@version AS VARCHAR(2)) +', ' +''''+@status+''''
      + @SEL 
 +'    FROM DBO.XLImport '


DECLARE cols_cursor CURSOR
   FOR (Select COLUMN_NAME From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = @tableName);
SET @SEL = ''; set @i = 0;
OPEN cols_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM cols_cursor INTO @field
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   set @sel = @sel + @field + ', '
   set @i   = 1;
   FETCH NEXT FROM cols_cursor INTO @field
END
CLOSE cols_cursor;
DEALLOCATE cols_cursor;

SET @SEL = LEFT(@SEL, LEN(@SEL) - 1) -- remove last ,


SET @SQL = N''
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SELECT * INTO XLImport FROM OPENROWSET'
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'('
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'''+','
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'''Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES;'
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'Database='+@file +''''+ ','
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'''select * from ['+ @SheetName + '$]'''+');'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

SET @SQLString =
N'INSERT INTO '+ @TableName + '('+ @SEL +') ' + @SQL;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to write (or generate) all reqiured procedures for all table. 23 tables times 4 procedures (insert, update, delete and select) that can be generated automatically is nothing in dev time and pain compared to the so called "generic solution".

It's a path to poor perfomance, unreadable code, sql injection hazard and countless debuging hours.

Comment: [Also, read my answer to a similar question a while back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684337/i-want-to-write-one-common-stored-procedure-to-insert-data-in-any-table-of-my-da/30690940#30690940)

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql`, here is example:

```
create proc sp_DynamicExcuteStore 
@TableName varchar(50),
@ColumnNames varchar(50),
@SQLResult varchar(max)
as
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '
INSERT INTO '+@TableName+' ('+@ColumnNames+')
    EXEC sp_executesql '+@SQLResult
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
go
create proc sp_test
as
select 'test' + convert(varchar,RAND())
go
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [text1] [nvarchar](500) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_DynamicExcuteStore]
        @TableName = N'Test',
        @ColumnNames = N'text1',
        @SQLResult = N'proc_test'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO

SELECT TOP 1000 [text1]
  FROM [test].[dbo].[Test]
```