# Pass a table name to a stored procedure's into statement

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to pass a table name to the below code but it is not working. The code will work when I do: SELECT X.* INTO dbo.RiskFactors_Tobacco but I can't seem to get it to work when I do: SELECT X.* INTO @RiskFactorsTable. Any suggestions?

```
CREATE TYPE typeRiskFactorsTable AS TABLE 
    (RiskFactorICD9 VARCHAR(10)) 

CREATE PROCEDURE dflt.GetRiskFactors 
    @RiskFactorICD9 typeRiskFactorsTable READONLY
    @RiskFactorsTable as VARCHAR(30)
AS

DECLARE @StartDate DateTime
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime
SET @StartDate = '2014-01-01 00:00:00'  
SET @EndDate = '2015-12-31 23:59:59'    

SELECT X.* 
INTO @RiskFactorsTable
FROM 
    (SELECT c.id, ip.AdmitDateTime as DateTime, ip.ICD9Code, ip.ICD9Description, 'IP' as DS
        FROM dbo.Inpat ip
            INNER JOIN dbo.COHORT c ON (c.ID = ip.ID)
            WHERE ip.ICD9Code IN (SELECT RiskFactorICD9 FROM @RiskFactorICD9)
                AND ip.AdmitDateTime between @StartDate and @EndDate 
    UNION ALL
        SELECT c.id, ov.VisitDateTime as DateTime, ov.ICD9Code, ov.ICD9Description, 'OP' as DS
        FROM dbo.Outpat_Visit ov 
            INNER JOIN dbo.Outpat ovd ON (ovd.ID = ov.ID)
            INNER JOIN dbo.COHORT sc ON (c.ID = ov.ID)
            WHERE icd.ICD9Code IN (SELECT RiskFactorICD9 FROM @RiskFactorICD9)
                AND  ov.VisitDateTime between @StartDate and @EndDate  
    ) X
    ORDER BY ID, DateTime, DS
GO

/*TOBACCO*/
DECLARE @RiskFactors typeRiskFactorsTable
INSERT @RiskFactors(RiskFactorICD9) 
    VALUES  ('305.1'), ('989.84'), ('V15.82');
EXEC dflt.GetRiskFactors @RiskFactors, @RiskFactorsTable = RiskFactors_Tobacco;
GO
```

Comment: table names can not be parameterized in t-sql. If you must, the only way is to use dynamic sql. beware of little booby tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Zohar pointed out in the comment, the table name can't be parameterized. Also, in case you were thinking of it, you can't use a table-valued parameter for the "select into" either.

From the [MSDN on the INTO clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx)

> You cannot specify a table variable or table-valued parameter as the new table.

Do you need to do a "select into"? Could you just do a "INSERT INTO DestinationTable SELECT ... FROM OriginationTable"? If you can do that, then the table-valued parameter should work. The INTO clause is just for when you want the select statement to simultaneously create a new table and insert into it.

Comment: I basically want to use the generic stored procedure for all of my RiskFactors, tobacco, COPD, hypotension, etc. I need a way to create the table that will contain the records for each of the RiskFactors. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @g83: [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414484/dynamic-t-sql-stored-procedure-to-insert-in-differents-tables/31416840#31416840)

Answer (score 0):

In the body of the procedure:

```
DECLARE @RiskFactorsTable TABLE (RiskFactorsICD9 varchar(10))
```

then

```
INSERT INTO @RiskFactorsTable
SELECT [one column]
FROM [table]
```

but you can't have a table as a SP paramater