# Designing flexible schema design in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I want to design a flexible schema design. When I say flexible schema design I mean that there are different tables in my database say School, Hospital, Police Stations.

Now I want to write a single proc in which the entity type (School, Hospital, Police Station) will be passed as a parameter. These tables will have different column names. So I am thinking of keeping the column I need to select from each table in a separate mapping table which will tell me which columns I need to select for different tables.

Also I will store the columns on basis of which data needs to be filtered out in the same mapping table. Is this the correct DB design? Can this lead to any bottlenecks when data size or number of entities increase?

- I know this is a classic case to use non-relational DBs like Mongo but due to some restrictions I have to use MySQL.

Comment: The MySQL [INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/columns-table.html) table already contains all the column names for the tables.

Comment: [Don't do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414484/dynamic-t-sql-stored-procedure-to-insert-in-differents-tables/31416840#31416840)

Answer (score 0):

If you do `SELECT *` and load it into a hash (associative array), you can get all the column names together with the data.

(This is one of the few cases where `*` is "OK" to use.)